# OpenCV C++ app terminates immediately when launched from Eclipse

Tags: c++, windows-7, opencv, eclipse-cdt

I'm currently having an issue getting a very small app using OpenCV launching from Eclipse.  The application launches fine from the command line, however when I launch it from Eclipse it simply terminates immediately with no output what so ever.  I would expect at least "Hello \o/" to be printed to the console.

I've found that it's only when I call a methods related to OpenCV that this happens.  So if I was to comment out all the lines related to OpenCV, I would see "Hello \o/" printed to the Eclipse Console.

I'm assuming the issue is something related to not been able to find the OpenCV DLL's at runtime (I stumbled across this problem initially at the command line, but resolved this by adding the OpenCV bin directory to the PATH variable).  I've tried adding this to my run configuration individually in Eclipse, but this makes no difference.

Any ideas what is causing this problem?

My Source:

```
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
cout << "Hello \\o/" << endl;
    /* data structure for the image */
    IplImage *img = 0;

    /* check for supplied argument */
    if (argc < 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: loadimg <filename>\n");
        return 1;
    }

    /* load the image,
     use CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE to load the image in grayscale */
    img = cvLoadImage(argv[1], CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
    /* always check */
    if (img == 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot load file %s!\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    /* create a window */
    cvNamedWindow("image", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

    /* display the image */
    cvShowImage("image", img);

    /* wait until user press a key */
    cvWaitKey(0);

    /* free memory */
    cvDestroyWindow("image");
    cvReleaseImage(&img);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't have any experience with OpenCV, but if I am seeing it right you should always get the Hello World output in the console. Anyway are you adding arguments in your run command? because you are explicitly asking for them...

Comment: Yea, I should always see "Hello" and I'm adding a single argument which is the input image, the code simply displays it.  I've actually managed to get it working in Eclipse by creating a fresh workspace, which leads me to believe that Eclipse simply isn't keeping up to date with my current environment.  I added the OpenCV bin directory after I'd created my workspace, although I did restart Eclipse afterwards.  At least now it just a matter of finding the difference in configuration between the two :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are most probably missing OpenCV's **lib** directory in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` (environment variable).

Comment: This worked for me by setting this in the Run configuration, thanks :).  I'm assuming Eclipse is generating this when the workspace is created (hense a new workspace working).  Do you know where I can set this at a workspace level rather than having to set it Run configuration?

Comment: If you want this setting to stick after a system reboot, edit your `~/.bashrc` and add: `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:path_to_opencv_libs`

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue. I checked and corrected all the paths first.

When nothing seemed to work, creating a new workspace worked out for me.